# Retrieve current image from specific View (Papaya)

Tags: javascript, html, papaya

I'm using the Papaya viewer to display medical images, and I'm currently facing an issue with retrieving a specific view's image when the viewer's HTML element is a canvas. The problem is that when I try to get the image, I only receive the entire canvas content, rather than the specific image I want.
Is there a JS function I can use to retrieve a specific image from the canvas?

Papaya viewer version: 1.0.1455

Browser: Safari

Operating System: MacOS

Comment: Are you trying to get the pixel data?  You probably want to use the Daikon library, instead of Papaya.